# How do you make an image uploaded with FileReader to the html canvas draggable?

Tags: html5-canvas

I read a few excellent posts on this site and Simon Sarris's [examples][1] but I have hit a wall. I am modifying one of the examples to drag and drop images I uploaded. It works for the first image, but not the second. Has anyone seen any examples of uploading a file using FileReader to the canvas, then dragging and dropping out there?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems

Uploading files to canvas using drag and drop

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images

Dragging and dropping image around canvas

- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Mikko,  Instead of dragging files on to the canvas, I'm trying to use the source from a fileReader upload:       img.src = event.target.result; and replace the source in the dragging and dropping  tutorial you mention:  var sources =

Comment: Sorry Mikko, I was referencing another tutorial on the htmlcanvastutorials site: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/ I'm just trying to adapt it so users can upload their own images.